# How can I convert a small image into an excel sheet with each pixel corresponding to a grayscale value?

Tags: r, excel, export-to-csv

I am doing a project where I am attempting to process hundreds of grayscale face images into excel format for further analysis.
Each image is 200 pixel by 200 pixel, so I am hoping to create hundreds of .csv files that have 200 column x 200 rows with elements of the corresponding image.
If there isn't any simple websites or software is there a way to do this in R or Visual Studio Code?

I tried to use several online converters, but they just outputted .csv files that had RGB values or an actual image within the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know R but, this Python script does the trick.

```
from PIL import Image #Python Image Library

def imgTOgrayscale(picture, width, outFileName):
    gsPx = [] #gray scale pixel values
    im = Image.open(picture) #open the image file
    pixels = list(im.getdata()) #convert the image file to a list of RGB values
    for i in pixels:
        gsPx.append(str((0.299 * i[0]) + (0.587 * i[1]) + (0.114 * i[2]))) #convert each RGB value to a grayscale value and append to a list as a string
    output = "" #a string to store the output
    horizontalCount = 0 #used in the for loop to know when to start a new line
    for i in gsPx: #loop through every pixel in the 2D list
        output += i #append the pixel to a string
        if (horizontalCount < width - 1): 
            horizontalCount += 1 #increment the counter by 1
            output += ',' #append a comma, needed to make the csv file
        else:
            output += '\n' #when the count has reached the width, start a new line and reset the counter
            horizontalCount = 0 #this is how we get a 3D list of strings
    file = open((outFileName), 'w') #create a file with the specified name, and open it in write mode
    file.write(output) #write the contents of 'output' to the file
    file.close() #close and save the file

imgTOgrayscale("myPic.png", 64, "myPic.csv")
```

You could run this in a for loop with all of your photos to get the CSVs.  I used a 64x64 image for my test but, you can simply replace my 64 width value with your image width (200).  I know you asked for an R solution but, seeing that there weren't any answers, I provided a Python solution.  I hope this helps!

Comment: You could always use the equation on line 8 to convert the RGB values from one of those online converters to grayscale values.  R should be well suited for performing math on each cell.